# Hyperledger join one org from one consortium to a channel in another consortium with already existing name. Best ways to do this

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Hyperledger Fabric 2.2

Current situation. We have two separate consortiums. Both have, however, channels with the same names. If I add Org from one consortium to the channel of another consortium I get error:

```
Error: proposal failed (err: bad proposal response 500: cannot create ledger from genesis block: ledger [data-channel] already exists with state [ACTIVE])
```

What's the best way to solve this situation? Do we have to rename a channel (is it possible?) in one of the consortiums? If I make a name-update config transaction, will the Couch DB databases follow this update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Fabric node cannot participate in two channels with the same name. You can simply have different nodes that each participates in one of the channels.